# hidden "not responding" dialog breaks the mouse for all applications

Tags: gnome

Sometimes, GNOME throws up one of these "not responding" dialogs *in the background*.

[image]

I cannot see this dialog, it is underneath other windows, but it has the side-effect of causing mouse clicks to be unresponsive for all applications globally.

This often happens when I am debugging, and it's a pain because I don't want to force the program to quit yet, so I have to hit "Wait" every few seconds.

Can I tell GNOME to let the mouse continue to work normally when this dialog is left up and unattended in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Got exactly the same issue with qtcreator and default Ubuntu here. This garbage x11-server-related bug is ongoing for at least six years.
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=981149

It was finally fixed here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/273.
Upgrading gnome-shell to 3.30+ should do it.

Answer (score -1):

Install the NoAnnoyance gnome shell extension.

Comment: Please expand your answer.